# Why is python-dotenv not working properly in Django project

Tags: python, django, dotenv

I'm trying to send django form data via email using *emails* module and *python-dotenv* for environment variables.

The *.env* file is along *settings.py* and it's loading the envs in *settings.py* accordingly, but I try this in *views.py* where I'm trying to set the aws ses credentials as environment variables, and everything seems to work, but the email is not sent, but then I re-enter the aws ses creds in plain back into *views.py* and everything works great again.

Any ideas why with envs the email is not sent?

Code in views.py

```
import os
import emails

from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv


load_dotenv(find_dotenv(), verbose=True)
...
```

part of code with creds:

```
...
            try:
                # Send the email
                r = message.send(
                    to= os.environ.get("RECEIPIENT"),
                    smtp={
                        "host": os.environ.get("HOST"),
                        "port": 587,
                        "timeout": 5,
                        "user": os.environ.get("USER"),
                        "password": os.environ.get("PASSWORD"),
                        "tls": True,
                    },
                )
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse(f"response{r.status_code == 250}")
```

I also tried this following the example in the official python-dotenv site using *os.getenv()*:

```
...
            try:
                # Send the email
                r = message.send(
                    to=os.getenv("RECEIPIENT"),
                    smtp={
                        "host": os.getenv("HOST"),
                        "port": 587,
                        "timeout": 5,
                        "user": os.getenv("USER"),
                        "password": os.environ.get("PASSWORD"),
                        "tls": True,
                    },
                )
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse(f"response{r.status_code == 250}")
```